# Select column header names based on column value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have the following data frame:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
row1    0      1    0         0      0
row2    0      0    0         0      1
```

I want to create a data frame like

```
row1    col2
row2    col5
```

Actaully I want to select the column names whose value is 1.

Comment: Welcome to SO @sovan , try to post code what  you have tried to do that

Comment: Can you assume that there is exactly one non-zero element in each row?

Comment: there will be exactly one column value with 1

Comment: first column is of string type other columns are either 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be

```
df.idxmax(1)
```

With your given test data:

```
In [113]: df
Out[113]:
      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
row1     0     1     0     0     0
row2     0     0     0     0     1

In [114]: df.idxmax(1)
Out[114]:
row1    col2
row2    col5
dtype: object
```

Based on what you mention comment below, if the column containing `'row1'` and `'row2'` is not already your index, you can use `df.set_index` first, then use `idxmax` as above:

```
In [120]: df
Out[120]:
  index  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0  row1     0     1     0     0     0
1  row2     0     0     0     0     1

In [121]: df.set_index('index').idxmax(1)
Out[121]:
index
row1    col2
row2    col5
dtype: object
```

Comment: first column is of string type other columns are either 0 or 1.in this scenario its failing

Comment: Then you can set that column to be your index using `df.set_index`, specifying the name of the column (i.e. what boils down to `df.set_index(df.columns[0])`).